# Array to repeat

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a = array(
array(
    "name" => "jack",
    "data" => "123",
    "link_uid" => "1",
),
array(
    "name" => "jack",
    "data" => "134",
    "link_uid" => "2",
),
array(
    "name" => "tom",
    "data" => "567",
    "link_uid" => "3",
),
array(
    "name" => "tom",
    "data" => "098",
    "link_uid" => "4",
)
);
```

to

```
$a = array(
array(
    "name" => "jack",
    "data" => "123",
    "link_uid" => "1",
),
array(
    "name" => " ",
    "data" => "134",
    "link_uid" => "2",
),
array(
    "name" => "tom",
    "data" => "567",
    "link_uid" => "3",
),
array(
    "name" => " ",
    "data" => "098",
    "link_uid" => "4",
)
);
```

Comment: unsure what you are trying to achieve here. Do you simply want repeated elements to be filtered out? Depending on your use case, you may be better off changing your data structure.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want just repeated name to blank

```
 <?php
 $temp = array();
 foreach($a as $key=>$value){
     if(in_array($value["name"],$temp)){
        $a[$key]["name"] = "";
     }else {
        $temp[] = $value["name"];
     }
 }
 print_r($a);
 ?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/855975